# Rotate html body via CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to rotate a html body via CSS. 
What i tried so far is the following code:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

I tried that in IE, Chrome and Firefox, but it don't work with any browser.
What I'm doing wrong?

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana;
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
/* Datumsanzeige aktueller Tag */

#head {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30pt;
  margin: 50px 0 30px 60px;
}
#page_navigation {
  bottom: 0;
  /*display: none;*/
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
}
table {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  border-spacing: 2px;
}
th {
  background-color: #009de0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
td div {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.content {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.c1 {
  background-color: #c7ebfc;
  width: 20%;
  color: #009de0;
}
.c2 {
  background-color: #c7ebfc;
  width: 20%;
  color: #009de0;
}
.c3 {
  background-color: #c7ebfc;
  width: 40%;
}
.c4 {
  background-color: #b9e6fb;
  width: 20%;
}
.c5 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.12, #D2D3D5), color-stop(0.25, #FFFFFF), color-stop(0.37, #D2D3D5));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #D2D3D5 3%, #FFFFFF 8%, #D2D3D5 15%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #D2D3D5 3%, #FFFFFF 8%, #D2D3D5 15%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #D2D3D5 3%, #FFFFFF 8%, #D2D3D5 15%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #D2D3D5 3%, #FFFFFF 8%, #D2D3D5 15%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #D2D3D5 3%, #FFFFFF 8%, #D2D3D5 15%);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
.c6 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 28px 0 0 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.c7 {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 1px;
}
.c8 {
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.c9 {
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.c10 {
  height: 332px;
  width: 627px;
}
.c11 {
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.c12 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="logo">
  </div>
  <div id="title">
    Seminar
  </div>
  <div id="head">
  </div>
  <hr />

  <div id='events_head'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class="c1">
          Seminar
        </th>
        <th class="c2">
          from
        </th>
        <th class="c3">
          to
        </th>
        <th class="c4">
          Buildung
        </th>
        <th class="c5">
          Room
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id='events'>
  </div>
  <!-- An empty div which will be populated using jQuery -->
  <div id='page_navigation'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It should work, do you have a fiddle with it?

Comment: Seems to work fine in Chrome & Firefox http://jsfiddle.net/ct7jnxkx/, what's "not  working" with your version?

Comment: It works properly. What content do you have inside `body` tags?

Comment: Post an [mcve], please.

Comment: I added the cotent of my body and my css code

Comment: I corrected the edit you made so that your HTML and CSS are runnable within your question, and it appears to work fine.

Comment: Seems to run fine for me as well.

Comment: This is so confusing to me. I tried it with jsfiddle now. In jsfiddle it is working but not in my Page. But thanks for help guys, i will try to find the problem

Comment: Did you properly load your CSS into the page?

Answer (score 0):

Although the code you provided seems to work, here's a jQuery solution you can try. (you didn't have jQ tagged, but it was in your code.)

I just wrote this plugin that rotates stuff.

```
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees,speed,d) {
    if(typeof speed == 'undefined') var speed = 50;
    if(typeof degrees == 'undefined') var degrees = 360;
    if(typeof d =='undefined') var d = 0;
    context = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(d);
        $(context).css({
            '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+d+'deg)',
            '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+d+'deg)',
            '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+d+'deg)',
            'transform' : 'rotate('+d+'deg)'
        });
        d++;
        if(d<=degrees) $(context).rotate(degrees,speed,d);
    },speed)
};
```

First param is the degrees to rotate, second is speed of rotation, ignore the third.

After adding the plugin code to your page you can do:

```
$('body').rotate(90, 10);
```

To rotate the page 90 degrees.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/63u1bgfw/